# How to merge two case classes and store them as one into a table?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/).

I have two case classes: `A` and `B`. I want to combine `A` and `B` and store the combination class into a database.

```scala
case class A (a: String, b: Int)
case class B (c: Double, d: Int)

//TODO  class C has the property of A and B
class C(val a: A, val b: B) {}

//Now I want to create a table for C
class Tb(tag: Tag) extends Table[C](tag, "a") {
  def col1 = column[String]("k1")
  def col1 = column[Int]("k2")
  def col1 = column[Double]("k3")
  def col1 = column[Int]("k4")
  def * = // TODO How to write * function?!
}
```

How to fill the `TODO` in the code above (in the `*` method)?

Comment: Are you using Slick (http://slick.typesafe.com) or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply teach Slick how to create an `A` from `k1` and `k2` and a `B` from `k3` and `k4` by a projection for each:

```
class Tb(tag: Tag) extends Table[ C ](tag, "a") {
  def col1 = column[String]("k1")
  def col2 = column[Int]("k2")
  def col3 = column[Double]("k3")
  def col4 = column[Int]("k4")
  // Add projections for A and B
  def a = (col1, col2) <> (A.tupled, A.unapply)
  def b = (col3, col4) <> (B.tupled, B.unapply)
  // And then use those projections to construct C
  def * = (a, b) <> (C.tupled, C.unapply)
}
```